# I have to add two pin annotation

Tags: swift

I have to change image of my pin annotation in MapKit. And there should be two pin. One of these should be current location, second one is selector new location

```
func mapView(\_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -\> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customannotation")
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"pin")
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("annotation title == \(String(describing: view.annotation?.title!))")
}
```

Comment: You can add as many annotations as you like.`viewFor` is called once for each annotation

Comment: If you want to set images for a few pins, you just need to loop over your images array. For example, you have an array of imageNames - let imageNames = ["", "", ""].    Then loop over the array- imageNames.forEach { index in                                                     annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: index) }

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I have to change image of my pin annotation in MapKit.

If you are saying that you have an annotation showing its associated annotation view on the map, and you want to change the image for that annotation view, you can add a property to your annotation to indicate which image is to be shown, and then have a custom `MKAnnotationView` object which observes the annotation’s property and updates its `image`, accordingly.

For example, consider an annotation that has an `imageName` property:

```swift
class CustomAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    @objc dynamic var imageName: String

    init(
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
        title: String? = nil,
        subtitle: String? = nil,
        imageName: String
    ) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        super.init()
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
}
```

Note, I made that an `@objc dynamic` property so that I can have an annotation view that observes that image name change:

```swift
class CustomAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CustomAnnotationView"

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet { addObserver(for: annotation) }
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addObserver(for: annotation)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    func addObserver(for annotation: MKAnnotation?) {
        let annotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation
        let imageName = annotation?.imageName ?? "red"
        updateImage(named: imageName)

        observer = annotation?.observe(\.imageName) { [weak self] annotation, _ in
            self?.updateImage(named: annotation.imageName)
        }
    }

    private func updateImage(named name: String) {
        let image = UIImage(named: name)
        self.image = image

        // the following is only needed if you want the bottom of the
        // image over the coordinates (e.g., you are using a “pin”).

        if let image = image {
            centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -image.size.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can create the annotation:

```swift
let annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate, imageName: "red")
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

And when you want, you can update the `imageName` associated for that annotation, and the annotation view will observe that value change, and update the image accordingly:

```swift
annotation.imageName = "black"
```

That yields:

[image]

---

> And there should be two pin. One of these should be current location, second one is selector new location

There is a special annotation for the user location, the `MKUserLocation`. Right now, your `mapView(_:viewFor:)` is returning `nil` for this annotation. Just change your `viewFor` to return whatever annotation you want for the `MKUserLocation` rather than `nil`.

Obviously this assumes (a) that you have enabled `showsUserLocation` property for your mapView and (b) that you have requested permission for the user’s location. E.g.:

```swift
private let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if manager.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    ...
}
```

And of course, set the appropriate privacy strings in `Info.plist`:

[image]